# Raspberry Pi Tor router without WLAN

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet, raspbian-wheezy, iptables

I have Raspberry Pi 1 model B+ with Raspbian Wheezy. I bought a USB2-Ethernet adapter and decided to create hardware Tor routing. What I mean by hardware routing:

The Raspberry Pi will be in middle of a computer and a router connected to each other with Ethernet cables. USB2-Ethernet adapter spawned network interface `eth1` and the normal ethernet port on the board is `eth0`. All traffic that comes from the `eth1` (computer) should be routed through Tor. The routing should not affect the connections of the middle box. I want to be able to SSH into the middle box as well as the box behind the Tor.

To accomplish this I followed [Adafruit's onion pi tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview) as well as [Install software](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software).

What I have done:

1. Followed the instructions to setup RasPi as access point carefully, but replaced `wlan0` with `eth1`. I didn't install `hostapd` but other things I did, including setting up `dhcp-server`, setting up `eth1` for static ip and finally configuring NAT.
2. Followed Onion pi instructions carefully.

Now the situation is as follows:

I have it set up but I cannot test it because I cannot SSH to the box behind the tor box. I planned to add some rule to middle-box's `iptables` so that connecting SSH to port 213 would instead route to port 22 of the box behind the tor box.

Issuing `ifconfig`, I get:

```
eth0: Inetaddr 192.168.0.104

eth1: Inetaddr 192.168.42.1
```

I tried adding the following rules to `iptables`

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 213 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.42.1:22


iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tp -d 192.168.42.1 --dport 213 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.42.1
```

But now when I `ssh pi@192.168.0.104 -p 213`, it routes somehow to the middle box's port 22 and I login to it instead of the one behind it!

Am I doing this in a stupid way? Should I take something into consideration? Any suggestions and help needed urgently! I've been struggling with this the whole day, all examples online haven't worked for my situation.